# Do different Web Hosts give different responses under same conditions?

Tags: java, php, web-hosting

I am working on an Android app. Therefore I'm creating a Login/Register Aktivity.I'm using JsonRequest (Volley) to get the Information stored in an SQL Data-base.Furthermore I wrote some PHP files (for Testing Purpose) to create a JSONObject as the Server Response.
Everything seems to work but only for some webhosts. What I mean by that is that the same Android Code and the same PHP Code once work fine and in the other case Output Errors.

My Test PHP Code uploaded via FileManagers

```
<?php
$myObj=new stdClass();
$myObj->name = "Test";
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

My Java Code

```
RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String success=response.getString("name");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ErrorCatch"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ErrorResponse"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Using one Webhost I get the Correct Toast including the stored Information from the Server. Using another Webhost I get an Error:"Java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" which I find Odd since I'm doing the same Stuff.

Comment: Possibly some other server configuration or php version. Maybe the faulty server has a very old php version, where json_encode is not yet implemented and throws an error. Try to access the php via browser or any api-client tester software to see what the return is.

Comment: also remove the trailing `?>` in your php script. In some cases sending additional space/tab/linefeed produces errors in receiving environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.One webhost is using php Version 7.0.19 and the other one php Version 7.1 which, as far as i know, both should include Jason_encode. Furthermore if i go to the url both Output "{"name":"Test"}" which seems like the correct and expected echo.